# Too many problems with Airpods on mac

Tags: mac, audio, bluetooth, airpods

When using **Airpods** with iPhone **only** everything works great, you put it on and start listening.

When you start to switch between your Mac and iPhone, I have problems. Most of the time, if I open the Airpods and connect them to the Mac, I will have this problem where every few seconds there is a second interrupt on sound (it stops). You can't hear music like that.

1. I'v tried to turn off Bluetooth on iPhone **before** connecting to the Mac, but this didn't work.
2. I'v tried to restart the Mac - and sometimes this doesn't work either.
3. I also ensured I have the latest firmware on the Airpots.

The experience is really not fun for a Mac user that switches between the Mac and an iPhone.

Does anyone have any other solutions or suggestions I can try to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question with the version of macOS that you are using.  (The model of Mac could be useful too.  iMac, MacBook Pro, MacBook Air, etc.) This may assist those who may have an answer.  Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I suspect you first have to ask if there is any known issues related to specific macOS version before I start adding unrelevant info. Do you know that there is a specific problem on specific machine/OS ? I don't ..

Comment: In case you're wondering, this is not the normal or expected behavior. It works fine for me switching between listening on audio from iPhone and Mac.

Comment: I have macOS 10.12 on macbook retina. Don't know what else to do. If the hardware works fine on the phone its probably not an hardware problem.

Comment: Many people have this problem.  See here for a more detailed analysis: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277923/airpods-choppy-unreliable-when-connected-to-mac-but-not-iphone

Comment: Curnelious, did the linked question that @Thomas posted have an answer that solved your problem?

Comment: I don't know if there is a solution. Connecting Airpods to Bluetooth 4.0 devices seems to be problematic. I also get a lot of WiFi interference (data rates on the Macbook go down a lot.)